# pybind11 access private class member via reference

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am given a class with a private variable `locked_`. This variable can be accessed via the methods `bool& locked();` and `bool locked() const;`

```
class Test {
    
  bool& locked();
  bool locked() const;
    
 private:
  bool locked_{true};
};
```

I am not allowed to alter class `Test`, yet I must write a pybind11 interface that allows both setting and retrieving `locked_`.

I cannot use `.def_readwrite("locked", &Test::locked_);` since `locked_` is of course private.
My attempts using

```
.def("locked", static_cast<bool& (Test::*)()>(&Test::locked), "locked", py::return_value_policy::reference_internal);
```

did compile however merely return a bool and not some sort of modifiable reference to bool.

How can I make locked read/write accessible without "touching" the original C++ implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still don't know pybind but I am starting to learn from your questions and I remember that `def` accepts lambdas. You can wrap the call to the member like this:

```
auto locker = [](Test& t, bool lock) { t.locked() = lock; };
```

I am not sure if you need to do something extra to make `def` work with your custom `Test`, so I suppose it can be used like this:

```
m.def("locker", locker);
```

Comment: You've learned more from two stranger's questions than me from 4h digging through the internet. #self-esteem

Comment: @FloRyan well, i didnt mean this to come across as arrogant. I do know lambdas and I have seen wrapping member functions into lambdas a couple of times. Without your input I wasnt able to answer your question (actually I tried to dig into the docs but I got confused pretty fast ;)

Comment: You certainly didn't come across as arrogant. Thanks for the help!